# Login and registration system using drupal - when user is created an email at our domain is also created

Tags: php, email, drupal-7

I have an experience of a year in websites developing, PHP, MYSQL, Javascript. And now I want to move on to using Drupal, the well know CMS. My question will follow in a bit but before I ask, this is what I'm trying to do now.

So, Im developing this website where an administrator can create an account at the company's website for an employee. When the account is created a username with a password will be handed to the employee as well as an email at the website domain with the same password as the one for the username. For example,  the employee John was added to the website by the admin. Now John has a username of lets say jhon, with password 123pass and an email with the address jhon@comanpyDomain.com with same password.

So my question is, is there a functionality from Drupal that I could use to do such a task of creating the username at the database of the website and then using some kind of API of the web host to create an email pragmatically at the same time the username was created. Also if there is a template of something that I could add to the website like an inbox where an employee could send and receive emails.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has [hook_user_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7) so You can leverage that and write custom module to create the post box for user **if** web host provides any api. For exampe cPanel has an API method [addpop](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/cPanel+API+2+Functions+-+Email%3A%3Aaddpop) to create new email account.

Comment: Thanks Bogdan, I looked followed the links you posted and they seem like a good start. However, I think Drupal is too sophisticated for a kind of a website like the one i'm developing right now. So, I guess I will use Joomla   for the task

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for this. It allows you to perform many actions based on events. eg. send an email on user account creation.
There's also the [Cpanel integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/cpanel) module which may be of help

Comment: Thank you Cadmonkey. I decided to use Joomla rather than Drupal because durpal is too complicated for the website I'm building